# using pandas to find the string from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a very beginner in programming and trying to learn to code. so please bear with my bad coding. I am using pandas to find a string from a column (Combinations column in the below code ) in the data frame and print the entire row containing the string . Find the code below. Basically I need to find all the instances where the string occurs , and print the entire row .find my code below . I am not able to figure out how to find that particular instance of the column and print it .

```
 import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("signallervalues.csv",index_col=False) 
data.head()
data['col1'] = data['col1'].astype(str)
data['col2'] = data['col2'].astype(str)
data['col3'] = data['col3'].astype(str)
data['col4'] = data['col4'].astype(str)
data['col5']= data['col5'].astype(str)
data.head()

combinations= data['Col1']+data['col2'] + data['col3'] + data['col4'] + data['col5']
data['combinations']= combinations
print(data.head())

list_of_combinations = data['combinations'].to_list()
print(list_of_combinations)

for i in list_of_combinations:
    if data['combinations'].str.contains(i).any():
        print(i+ 'data occurs in row' )
        # I need to print the row containing the string here 
    else:
        print(i +'is occuring only once')
```

my data frame looks like this

[image]

Comment: can you try to explain what are you trying to get I'm not sure i understand you... and good luck in programming!

Comment: Do you want to search for a specific value (data['combinations'].str.contains(i).sum())? Where is the .sum defined? Could you give the result of print(data.head()) in here for a better understanding?

Comment: I have 6 columns in my data frame and all are strings. I need to search through the column 6 ( combinations in my code ) and find the number of occurrences of that instance and print all the occurrence of the string.

Comment: @squeezer44 : I have added the result of data.head() in the post

Comment: @squeezer44 : the sum is irrelevant . I am sorry it should have been .any()

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.DataFrame()

# recreating your data (more or less)

data['signaller']= pd.Series(['ciao', 'ciao', 'ciao'])
data['col6']= pd.Series(['-1-11-11', '11', '-1-11-11'])

list_of_combinations=['11', '-1-11-11']


data.reset_index(inplace=True)

# group by the values of column 6 and counting how many times they occur
g=data.groupby('col6')['index']


count= pd.DataFrame(g.count()) 


count=count.rename(columns={'index':'occurences'})
count.reset_index(inplace=True)

# create a df that keeps only the rows in the list 'list_of_combinations'
count[~count['col6'].isin(list_of_combinations)== False]
```

My result

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it shows key error
KeyError: '-1-11-11'

Comment: I also don't need the count . I would like to find out the number of occurrences and print that column from data frame to separate data frame .

Comment: thanks @coelidonum , it works for me. Can you also help me   print the rows of each occurrence for example cluster it based on occurrence .in your code (-1-11-11) combination occurs twice and can we  put those two rows in a separate data frame , and the single occurrence in another data frame and so on .

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it. Do you want as many dataframes as the different values of col6?

Comment: Yes I want to create a dataframe with unique columns and their respective rows.  like if a value (col6) occurs only once I need to create a data frame with that occurrence row, and if it occurs twice I need to create another data frame with 2 instances of that column .